# Uncomment XML using Java (DOM)

Tags: xml, comments

I'm trying to access an XML file using DOM.  One node is already commented out.  How do I uncomment it using java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment is a special node in DOM. See the [Comment](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Comment.html) class. A comment could indeed contain anything, including wrongly formatted code. So there is not such thing as toggle comment/uncomment in DOM, even if that's what we are used to do as developper.

So to uncomment, I guess you will need to remove the node, and create a regular DOM node that correspond to your need. You may need to parse the comment content returned by [Comment#getData()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/CharacterData.html#getData%28%29).